# Getting output from many lines in one single table

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file as below:

```
number=49090005940;

NUMBER TRANSLATION DATA

NUMBER DATA

NUMBER           TYPE        SUBCOND

49090005940      IN

NUMPRE

1117230111

END


number=49090005942;

NUMBER TRANSLATION DATA

NUMBER DATA

NUMBER           TYPE        SUBCOND

49090005942      IN

NUMPRE

1117230111

END
```

I want to have an output with "NUMBER, TYPE, and NUMPRE as below:

```
NUMBER=49090005940; TYPE=IN; NUMPRE=1117230111;

NUMBER=49090005942; TYPE=IN; NUMPRE=1117230111;
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself? Post your research efforts here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mouthful, but it works.

```
 awk '/number=/{split($0, a, "[=;]"); nump=a[2]} nextrec==1 && /[^ ]/{num=$0; nextrec=0} /NUMPRE/{nextrec=1} $1==nump{ty=$2} /END/{print "NUMBER="num"; TYPE="ty"; NUMPRE="nump";"}' infile
```

Here awk:

1. If it finds a record matching `"number="` (`/number=/` then it splits the record by an equal sign or a semicolon and stores it in array `a` (`split($0, a, "[=;]");`). It then puts the second element of the array into variable `nump` (`nump=a[2]`).
2. It looks for a line containing the word `NUMPRE` (`/NUMPRE/`) if it finds it, it sets variable `nextrec` to 1 (`nextrec=1`).
3. If `nextrec` is set to 1 and the record contains no spaces (`nextrec==1 && /[^ ]/`) then set variable `num` to the line (`num=$0`).
4. If the line starts with what is stored in `nump` (`$1==nump`) then store the second field of that record in variable `ty` (`ty=$2`).
5. Finally if we hit a record containing `END` (`/END/`) then print the output desired(`print "NUMBER="num"; TYPE="ty"; NUMPRE="nump";"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working exactly as per my requirement :)

Comment: Oops !! Its giving a bit wrong output. NUMPRE has the value of NUMBER while as NUMBER has the value of NUMPRE :S

Comment: awk '/number=/{split($0, a, "[=;]"); nump=a[2]} nextrec==1 && /[^ ]/{num=$0; nextrec=0} /NUMPRE/{nextrec=1} $1==nump{ty=$2} /END/{print "NUMBER="nump"; TYPE="ty"; NUMPRE="num";"}' infile

Comment: I thought that was backwards, but I was going from your example up top. Your switch around of the variables is good.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n\n\n' -v OFS='; ' -v ORS=';\n' '{print $7"="$10, $8"="$11, $12"="$13 }' file
NUMBER=49090005940; TYPE=IN; NUMPRE=1117230111;
NUMBER=49090005942; TYPE=IN; NUMPRE=1117230111;
```

Comment: Hi Ed, Yes its because of extra lines. I am not able to use the awk given by you :(

Comment: OK, I tweaked it to work with exactly the sample input shown in your question, extra blank lines and all!